# Changing sidenote size

Tags: fontsize, sidenotes

I'd like to change the size of my sidenote text to `\footnotesize`. Why can't I just redefine `\sidenotetext` with `\footnotesize` where I need it, as below?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{sidenotes}

\makeatletter
    \RenewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { o o +m }
    {
        \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
            {
            \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~#3}
        \refstepcounter{sidenote}
    }
            {\@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\footnotesize\textsuperscript{#1}\footnotesize~#3}}
    }
\makeatother    

\begin{document}

Hello\sidenote{Hi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF`? Ah, that's an invention by `sidenotes` package. You're missing a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I think it is because the `\@sidenotes....` macros expand somewhere else so `\makeatletter` isn't needed actually

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are right...as usual.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: :D ... but `\makeatletter...\makeatother` does not harm here anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You should/could have mentioned that you use the original definition from
>   the `sidenotes` package and try to change the definition of one of the
>   commands using the functionality of the `xparse` package which is loaded automatically with the `sidenotes` package.

I replaced `\@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~#3}` with `\@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~\footnotesize#3}` (added `\footnotesize` before `#3`).

In addition, thanks to Christian Hupfer, you need to enclose the definition with `\makeatletter...\makeatother` since the code uses the `@` symbol in the not literal way (see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
%% Loads the following packages
% marginnote
% caption
% xparse
% l3keys2e
% changepage

%%% From the sidenotes documentation
%% \sidenote
%% Uses \sidenotetext
%\NewDocumentCommand\sidenote { o o +m }
%{
%\sidenotemark[#1]
%\sidenotetext[#1][#2]{#3}
%\@sidenotes@multimarker
%}
%
%% \sidenotetext
%% Used in \sidenote
%\NewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { o o +m }
%{
%\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
%{
%\@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~#3}
%\refstepcounter{sidenote}
%}
%{\@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{#1}~#3}}
%}

% \sidenotetext
% Used in \sidenote
% Changed to meet the question of user J. Bratt (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361622).
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\sidenotetext{ o o +m }{%      
    \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}{%
        \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~\footnotesize#3}%
        \refstepcounter{sidenote}%
    }{%
        \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{#1}~#3}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello\sidenote{Hi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So do I understand that correctly, if I'm just using `sidenotes`, and I want to for example change the font size of a `\marginpar{...}` in my text, it is really *that* complicated?

Comment: I recommend using this in conjunction with the [marginfix](https://ctan.org/pkg/marginfix?lang=en) package, which takes care in case you have several long sidenotes that exceed the length of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the logical query a little bit, using the ordinary `\IfValueTF{#1}{}{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sidenotes}



\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\sidenotetext{oo+m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\footnotesize\textsuperscript{#1}\footnotesize~#3}
  }{%
    \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}~#3}%
    \refstepcounter{sidenote}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Hello\sidenote[foo]{Hi}

Hello\sidenote{Hi again}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :) Same idea at the same time.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Apparently....